# ajax response data is undefined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

i have problem with ajax post submit
here is my script

```
function postad(actionurl) {
        if (requestRunning) return false ;

        if (! $("#editadform").valid()) {
            validator.focusInvalid();
            return false ;
        }

        $('#ajxsave').show() ;
        requestRunning = true ;
        var postData = $('#editadform').serializeArray();
        $.ajax(
        {
            url : actionurl,
            type: "POST",
            data : postData,
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
            {
                $('#diverrors').html(data.errors) ;
                $('#divalerts').html(data.alerts) ;

                if (data.status=='success') {  alert(data.status);
                  $('#siteid').val(data.siteid) ;
                  if ($('#adimager').val())
                    $('#divlmsg').html(data.alertimage) ;
                  $('#editadform').submit() ;

                } else {

                  $('#ajxsave').hide() ;
                }
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
            {
                $('#ajxsave').hide() ;
            },
            complete: function() {
                requestRunning = false;
            }
        });

        $('.btn').blur() // remove focus
        return false ;
    }
```

This works on  `if (textStatus=='success') {`

but when the action fails, `alert(data.status)` shows Undefined.

Using FireBug, I can see that the data is correctly returned. Why is data.status "Undefined" then?

Comment: if you write console.log(data) what are you getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify the `dataType` field of an `$.ajax()` call in jQuery, it formats the response as plain text. A workaround to your code would be to either include `dataType: "JSON"` into your `$.ajax()` parameters, or alternatively, in your `success` function, parse the plain text response as a JSON object, by using the folllowing:

```
data = JSON.parse(data); // You can now access the different fields of your JSON object
```

**UPDATE:**

> yes i have not `status` field in action url, how to add data status field in php code?

When creating your PHP script that is intended to return the JSON data, you first need to build an array and then encode it as JSON.

So, suppose you have a PHP script that either succeeds and produces some data that you put into a `$data` variable, or fails, then the following style could be adopted:

```
<?php
    // ^^ Do your PHP processing here
    if($success) { // Your PHP script was successful?
        $response = array("status" => "success!", "response" => $data);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        $reponse = array("status" => "fail", "message" => "something went wrong...");
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
?>
```

Comment: Which approach did you try? Also, is your JSON actually returning what you think it is? It could be that your JSON object doesn't have a `status` field?

Comment: yes i have not `status` field in action url, how to add data status field in php code?

Comment: I changed the php file header to:  `header('Content-type: application/json');`  And the problem was solved, thank you